# FOSRestBundle 2.4 | How to load rest type route

Tags: symfony, routes, yaml, fosrestbundle

I upgraded my FOSUserBundle to 2.4 from 2.1 while I was upgrading my project to Symfony 3.4 from 2.8.

With the same code that worked before, and this `yml` file:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
api_request_backend:
    type: rest
    prefix: /api
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/default.yml"
```

-

```
# AppBundle/Resources/config/default.yml
api:
    type: rest    # This resource will have RESTful routes
    prefix:
    resource: "@AppBundle\Controller\ApiController"
    name_prefix: api_
apiV2:
    type: rest    # This resource will have RESTful routes
    prefix: /v2
    resource: "@AppBundle\Controller\ApiV2Controller"
    name_prefix: api_v2_
api_user:
    type: rest    # This resource will have RESTful routes
    prefix:
    resource: "@AppBundle\Controller\ApiUserController"
    name_prefix: api_
```

I receive this error:

> Exception thrown when handling an exception
>   (Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException: The file
>   "/var/www/project/src/AppBundle/Resources/config/default.yml" does
>   not contain valid YAML in
>   /var/www/project/src/AppBundle/Resources/config/default.yml (which
>   is being imported from "/var/www/project/app/config/routing.yml").
>   Make sure there is a loader supporting the "rest" type.)

Where am I wrong? I also tried to downgrade FOSRestBundle to 2.3.1 (I read this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48470527/fosrestbundle-symfony-3-4-rest-type-not-reconized)) but nothing changes.

Comment: I tried to enhance the formatting (indentation) of your code, but there are missing values for `prefix` in two occasions. That couldn't work. Would you please take a look at your code example and eventually correct those two lines?

Comment: the prefix field are not required, the solution below works right with null values.

Comment: thanks! I struggle with the same error. Your question and answer are valuable resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the invalid YAML. The following works:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
api_request_backend:
    type: rest
    prefix: /api
    resource: '@AppBundle/Resources/config/default.yml'
```

and

```
# AppBundle/Resources/config/default.yml
api:
    type: rest    # This resource will have RESTful routes
    resource: '@AppBundle\Controller\ApiController'
    name_prefix: api_
```

thanks to [xabbuh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2289865/xabbuh) for the fix

Comment: The only relevant change I see is converting the double quotes to single quotes. Was that really the solution or I'm missing something more important here.

Comment: yes, with the upgrade the double quotes are not valid

Answer (score 2):

For newest (>3.0) you must change the route type from rest to annotation.